# Como seleccionar un registro que tenga asociado el max en mysql

Tags: mysql

| id | territorio |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2677 |
| 6 | 169 |
| 7 | 654 |
| 7 | 1238 |

tengo este resultado despues de hacer una consulta en sql pero debo dejar un solo registro por Id y  la fila que debo dejar es la que tenga mayor valor en la columna territorio entre los repetidos. es decir para el ID 6 debo dejar la fila con territorio igual a 2677 y para ID 7 la fila con territorio igual a 1238.

como lo podría hacer?

---

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID,e.LastName,e.FirstName,e.Title,e.TitleOfCourtesy,et.TerritoryID from employees e 
inner join employeeterritories et on (e.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID)
where e.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Mr.' order by et.TerritoryID desc ;
```

esta es la consulta que hago y la salida es esta, lo que señale con azul es lo debria elegir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes intentar hacer un GROUP BY por campo id, le aplicas  la funcion MAX al campo territorio

Comment: Podrías colocas tu SQL de la consulta que haces?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Lee los enlaces que te pase... tenias un boton para agregar info en tu pregunta.. y en la parte que dice respuestas... van solo respuestas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para traer el valor máximo existe *max()*:

```
SELECT id, max(territorio)
FROM tuTabla
GROUP BY id
```

Al agregar la cláusula Group By, agruparemos los Id. Sino lo usas,  solo devolverá el registro más alto.

---

Cómo se sugiere, explicaré brevemente la funcionalidad del [GROUP BY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_(SQL)).

Está cláusula nos permite agrupar filas que contengan el mismo valor. En este caso, como tú tienes muchos **id** repetidos, esta cláusula los agrupará y nos mostrará una única fila por id.

Comment: En general, siempre tratamos de esperar a que OP demuestre lo que intento hasta ahora.. si no, solo le estamos resolviendo el ejercicio...

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, en un momento de despiste no presté atención a la pregunta y no controlé que haya escrito su intento. Ha sido un error mío

Comment: Bueno ahora agrego un ejemplo valido... y la respuesta es esta.. pero tal vez, explicarle que hace un group by y como funciona seria mejor no??? (igual, en el sitio debe estar mil veces)

Comment: He seguido tu consejo y he comentado brevemente su funcionalidad

Comment: No es que quiera que me resuelvan el ejercicio simplemente si pueden ver es mi primera pregunta entonces no es que conozca la dinámica, perdón si se sintieron ofendidos.

Comment: Nadie se ha ofendido, es que he cometido el error de dejar una respuesta sin controlar que tu pregunta haya tenido tu código de ejemplo o lo que intentaste. Ya que, al no tener código y solo ser una pregunta, estas tienden a cerrarse. Ha sido un despiste mío. Si está respuesta ha ayudado a resolver tu problema, puedes marcarla como correcta (palomita/check) En caso contrario, deja un comentario

Comment: @AlexandraBerrioJaramillo nadie se ofendio.. Estamos tratando de que aprendas a usar la plataforma, para que tus proximas preguntas sean bien recibidas y no tengamos que pedirte aclaraciones, y puedas estar mas comoda en la misma...